# How do I convert type of a datetime string which has Z in it

Tags: python, string, datetime, iso

I have a datetime string like this: `2021-11-13T09:20:15.497Z`, I'm just wondering how can I convert this into a datetime object?
I tried `datetime.datetime.fromiso()` but it told me that the format is not an iso format
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [efficient work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418) to use `fromisoformat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"` format

```
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.strptime("2021-11-13T09:20:15.497Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(x)              # 2021-11-13 09:20:15.497000+00:00
print(x.isoformat())  # 2021-11-13T09:20:15.497000+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Will mark it as an answer in a few minutes!

Comment: Z (= UTC) should not be ignored by using a literal Z in the parsing directive. Why? Because it gives you naive datetime, which Python treats as local time, which is most likely not UTC. You can use %z in the directive.